# Displaying Item from Listbox onto Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to display an item from a CSV file onto listbox(this part works) and then display individual parts of that item in separate labels.

```
public partial class InventoryForm : Form
    {
        public InventoryForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

public List<ItemsList> itemsLists(string csvPath)
        {
            var query = from l in File.ReadAllLines(csvPath)
                        let data = l.Split('|')
                        select new ItemsList
                        {
                            Name = data[0],
                            Type = data[1],
                            DMGTyp = data[2],
                            DMG = data[3],
                            Weight = int.Parse(data[4]),
                            Price = int.Parse(data[5]),
                            Description = data[5]
                        };
            return query.ToList();
        }
        private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog filePath = new OpenFileDialog();
            filePath.ShowDialog();
            textBox1.Text = filePath.FileName;
        }

        private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.DataSource = itemsLists(textBox1.Text);
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //to do show individual pieces in labels
            
        }
    public class ItemsList
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string DMGTyp { get; set; }
        public string DMG { get; set; }
        public int Weight { get; set; }
        public int  Price { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The items are broken up into 6 parts and the list box only shows the name of the item but I want the label to show the rest of the item's properties. Any clues on how to do that?

Comment: Add a DataBinding to the Labels, setting the binding to the corresposnding property of the `ItemsList` class. The selected `ItemsList` object is returned by the `ListBox.SelectedItem`. BTW, you cut off some pieces of code and left off the `ItemsList` class definition. Use a BindingSource to *link* your `List<ItemsList>` objects to the DataSource of the ListBox and use it as the source of the DataBindings.

Comment: `ItemList` is the class created by you? You should create a form level variables `List<ItemsList> items` and populate the list from CSV file... you can load the ListBox from `item` and when user selects item from listbox, you can use query the `items` using LINQ to get the item based on selected Name. and then display other properties of that item in the labels.

Comment: I haven't played with data bindings up to this point in my learning do you know any good source to learn it in?

Comment: Declare the BindingSource as a Field: `private BindingSource listSource = null;` ... after you have created the List... `listSource = new BindingSource([Your List], null); listBox1.DisplayMember = "[The Name of the Property used to present the List]"; listBox1.DataSource = listSource; label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", listSource, "Name", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged); label2.DataBindings.Add(...) [...]`. After that, it's all automatic, no need to handle events.